# Show Google results along with related questions

Tags: feature-request, google, related-questions

A significant number of downvotes are given to questions whose askers didn't first check Google. This seems to be closely related to downvotes from asking a question with duplicates in the "Related Questions" field. How about also showing Google's "I'm feeling lucky," or some other results, in the Related Questions to help out with that?

EDIT: to clarify, I'm not talking about questions with answers on Stack Overflow, but rather questions with easy solutions available via Google. Here's a question just like that: [3D plotting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809224/what-are-my-options-for-3d-plotting-in-python)

Comment: Would it stay specific to the site or would it encompass the whole internet? Because if its the latter, then **NO!!!**

Comment: With millions of garbage questions and duplicates, it is time to rethink this.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, provided the search used is:

```
my search terms site:stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the semi-official long-term goals here is to make a Stack Exchange post show up as the top Google result for most objective questions. This proposed feature would be redundant if that goal were achieved. And of course, if the easy questions aren't asked here, they won't show up as Google results.

Until Stack Overflow Internet Services achieves its goal, enjoy the easy rep you get for answering easily Google-able questions!

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to come around to the majority way of thinking about this.  If a question easily answered by google is not answered on SO, it's because it still *needs* an answer on SO, so it's a good thing that users are not deterred from asking those questions.

Maybe a decent middle ground is, after a question has been posted on SO, an additional link taking to to google for the same content appears someplace obvious, for both askers and answerers to use.